# How to get value from radio buttons and display in textview

Tags: android

This is layout for radio buttons I have added.

I  set the radio button `@+id/radio1` with the value 10, `@+id/radio2` with the value 9 and `@+id/radio3` with the value 8 .. how to get the value in radio button and then multiply it by 3? for example `@+id/radio1(10) * 3`?

XML:

```
           <RadioButton
                 android:id="@+id/radio1"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="10"
                 android:checked="false"/>
           <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="9"
                android:checked="false"/>
           <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="8"
                android:checked="false"/>`
```

Comment: you want to multiply the selected radiobutton value with 3?? am i right

Comment: yes i'm .. i want the selected radiobutton multiple with 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <RadioGroup
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="90dp"
          android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
          android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
          android:weightSum="1"
          android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
          android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
          android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
          android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
          android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3">

          <RadioButton
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="55dp"
             android:text="1"
             android:id="@+id/radio1"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:checked="false"
             android:textSize="25dp" />

          <RadioButton
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="2"
             android:id="@+id/radio2"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:checked="false"
             android:textSize="25dp"
             android:layout_weight="0.13" />

          <RadioButton
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="3"
             android:id="@+id/radio3"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:checked="false"
             android:textSize="25dp"
             android:layout_weight="0.13" />
       </RadioGroup>
```

Surround your radio buttons with a [RadioGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) this will make it easier to find the right radio button that has been selected.

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
 {
  @Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) 
     {
       switch (checkedId) {
          case R.id.radio1:
           RadioButton value = Integer.parseInt(((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1).getText()) * 3);
          break;
          case R.id.radio2:
           RadioButton value = Integer.parseInt(((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2).getText()) * 3);
          break;
          case R.id.radio3: 
         RadioButton value = Integer.parseInt(((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3).getText()) * 3);
          break;
   }
  }
});
```

This code listens for any activity going on inside the `RadioGroup` and then gets the `selectedId` of the `radioButton` that has been selected, gets the value from that and then multiplies it by 3. From here you can make `value` a global instance (`private int value;`) and use it anywhere else in your Activity. E.g. setting a text field (`textView.setText(String.valueOf(value));`)

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow. if it works, please accept the answer via the green tick next to the answer.

Comment: sorry . i want to ask one more question about that coding . i copy that code and paste in to my code but it cannot resolve method getText() . can you help me ? thank you

Comment: i wrote it from the top of my head so there's a bracket out of place copy the new lines in and it should work.

Comment: hello , i have a question .. i try the code into my java .. but it say operator '*' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.charSequence.'int' .. how to solve it ?

Comment: I couldn't tell you without you asking another question

Comment: what i mean is , i try this code that have given by you but i could solve the problem , which mean . i write case R.id.radio1:
            value = Integer.parseInt(((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1)).getText() * 3); but the error is operator '*' cannot be applied

Comment: Oh my apologies you'll have to sort the brackets properly I wrote this from the top of my head, I'll sort it out when I get onto my laptop

Answer (score 0):

you can listen to click events on the radio buttons and then inside that onClick event you can set the text to the `TextView` by:

```
textview.setText("1");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

        // get selected radio button from radioGroup
    int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    // find the radiobutton by returned id
        radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
       String value = radioSexButton.getText().toString();
            int result = Integer.parseInt(value);

            int finalvalue= result * 3;
            Log.e("result", "" + finalvalue);


    }

});
```

Comment: hello , i use this method value * 3 but it have an error which are operator '*' cannot be applied to java.lang.charSequence.int'

Comment: yes i already use .. i just copy your code .. but it error at the operator , it said operator '*' cannot be applied .. hmm